# Detect whether certain unicode characters will render properly

Tags: blackberry, unicode

I am developing a BlackBerry application that displays Malayalam characters. But some devices do not support those characters.  For example the 9550 I am testing with displays rectangles instead of the correct character. How can I know whether a device supports Malayalam character rendering?

Comment: What do you mean by “Unicode”, and what do you mean by saying that some devices do not support Unicode? What would you do with the information?

Comment: I would like to display malayalam text and I am giving text as &#3378;&#3398;&#3385;&#3400;&#3349;&#3405;&#3349; in 9300,9800,9900 are displaying malayalam correctly and in 9550 it is displaying as rectangles

Comment: "Displayed as rectangles" means the device *supports Unicode* but lacks a **font** for Malayalam. That may be a bit difficult to detect...

Comment: the same code is dispayed in 9800,9900,9700